# なら and から what's the relation?

Tags: grammar

> A：この本を読んでみてください。
>
> B：これ**なら**難しくない**から**、私にも読めそうです。

Google translator said "This is not difficult, so I can read it."
It's somehow convincing translation but I don't yet get the meaning of なら and から here in this sentence.

Comment: If possible don't rely on google translate

Answer (score 3):

なら and から are not related. It seems that some intermediate grammars were used to construct that sentence.

なら is a conditional=if (1 out 4 of them). It is used on a given context. It means "if given that ... Then ..." In which the context is taken from the conversations. A here told B to try reading the book.

これなら means "If given that it's this book then...". The book is already implied so it's not being stated again. AならB => if given that A then B.

から connects two sentences with the preceding sentence is the reason and the sentence after it is the result. To say, it means "because".  AからB => Because of A, B happens.

難しくないから、私にも読めそうです means "Because it(the book) is not difficult, it seems that even I can read it"

Combined it means "Given that It's this book and it's not difficult, it seems that even I can read it."